# Only getting draft options - no "show this item"

Tags: 2sxc

When we are editing content, the only 2 options we see are "hide this item" and "hide changes as draft". The "show this item" is not there at all unless you go into the Admin and edit the item that way.

The console also has a line that reads "publishing: DraftRequired"

Is there a setting somewhere that needs to be set to allow publishing?

Comment: hii welcome to stack overflow please explain your question more clearly and tag it properly so that it can reach right people to answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're using Evoq and have the page-workflow set to require publishing. That would cause this, as 2sxc respects Evoq page publishing.

Comment: We are using Evoq but are using the Direct Publish Workflow type on all pages of the site. The option to "show" the changes isn't there unless we go into the Admin where we then need to find the draft, open it, and change it to "show this item".

Comment: So this most likely related to that. I don't know if 2sxc is getting a wrong info from evoq, or if it's behaving incorrectly, but 2sxc tries to respect Evoq workflows and this seems to be a bug on either DNN/Evoq or 2sxc. 
I don't have a quick-fix for you, this would take in-depth investigation of a few hours, maybe even 1-2 days to find, report and/or fix.